# Change user agent of an iframe

Tags: javascript

I would like to change the user agent of an iframe for XMLHtpptRequest. I did that, but that does not work! Any idea to do that?

```
  <iframe id="myiframe"></iframe> 
  <script>

   var x = document.getElementById("myiframe").contentWindow;

   XMLHttpRequest.prototype.orig2Open = x.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
   x.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open   = function () {
        this.orig2Open.apply(this, arguments);
        this.setRequestHeader('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0 Chrome/90.0.1180.83');
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Is the iframe's src in the same origin (domain) as the one running this script?

Comment: no problem with CORS

Comment: It's not about CORS, it's about the fact that you can't alter code in an iframe you don't own.